# Google Looker Dynamic Dashboards

Tags: dynamic, dashboard, looker-studio, looker

We have a requirement to build dynamic dashboards using Looker studio. We are gathering data from different projects into a warehouse (ELT involved) and then making it available to Looker studio for building dashboards. These projects have varying fields (some fields are common and some are different). We don't want to build separate dashboard for each project. Instead, we would like to build a dynamic dashboard that can be used for all the projects with right level of drill down. What's the best way to achieve that in Looker if we don't want to change our ELT process?

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding your question correctly you would like to link multiple data tables in Looker studio without changing the ELT process.

Looker Studio is a visualization tool and is not ideal for processing large amounts of data the things like power BI can, But so long as you have a common identifier between the tables you should be OK.

You can Blend tables from different data sources together providing they have at least one thing in column in common [How to Blend](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9061420?hl=en). The problem with this approach is you can not add fields to a blended data table, use have to add a field to the visual.

or

As long as these columns have identical names the "controls" should filter both tables at the same time. This means can provide to illusion of a single data source when really it is from many. For some reason this does not work 100% of the time so I also create metrics in one table and change their field ID to match the field ID in the table I am trying to link to [image] .

Hopefully this has been of some help.

Comment: The need is for a UNION rather than JOIN. Let's say Table1 has columns project_id, ticket_id, title, description, priority, size, value_area and status and Table2 has columns project_id, ticket_id, title, description, severity, tshirt_size, category, status and approach. Here, some column names are different - priority vs severity, size vs tshirt_size, value_area vs category and there is extra column in Table2 called approach. Variability could be more in terms of column names and number of columns. How can we maintain a common looker dashboard for all tables in this case?

Comment: And we may sometimes want to see data for Table1, sometimes for Table2 and sometimes for both together.

Comment: @PrafulKhandelwal I would use a full outer join, to merge the 2 tables together and then use the coalesce function to combine the fields that are the same ie project_id, then you should have field that will combine both in looker studio. if you have any numbers you will have to use an IFNULL to remove the nulls